# wierd compile time error: method push_back could not be resolved

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code dealing with a vector within a vector. I am getting a very strange compile-time error while working with eclipse.

I am trying to copy the contents of an existing entry in the column_info vector to a new column_info vector in a new table_info vector.

```
  typedef struct _column_info
 {
char name[20]; // Column Name
int type; // 0:INT, 1: CHAR
int size;
int offset; // Start Position
 } column_info;

  typedef struct _table_info
 {
char name[20]; // Table Name
char columns[100];
vector<column_info> col;
char primary_key[20];
int recordsize;
int totalsize;
int records;
  } table_info;

  vector<table_info> v;

  table_info* get_table_info(const string& tablename)
  {
for (int i = 0; i < (int) v.size(); i++)
{
    if (strcmp(v.at(i).name, tablename.c_str()) == 0)
        return &v.at(i);
}
return NULL;
   }

  void select_table_nested(char* tablename, char* select_column[], int column_cnt[],      int nested_cnt, int select_column_count)
  {
   table_info* table_info;
   table_info = get_table_info(tablename);
   table_info new_table;
   column_info cols;

   for( int k =0; k < table_info->col.size(); k++)
   {
     strcpy(cols.name, table_info->col.at(k).name);
     cols.type = table_info->col.at(k).type;
     cols.size = table_info->col.at(k).size;
     cols.offset = table_info->col.at(k).offset;
     new_table.col.push_back(cols); ---> field 'col' could not be resolved
                                    ---> Method 'push_back' could not be resolved
    }
   }
```

Am I missing out on something? Because I am performing a push_back operation in other parts of this same code (in different functions) and not getting this error, except in this particular function. Please help.

Comment: You should work on your indentation, and in general in making the code a little more C++ and less C. For example, the `typedef`s are not required in C++ (in general), and if you are in the global namespace, `_table_info` and `_column_info` are reserved identifiers for the implementation (compiler + library). The use of `char` arrays should probably be replaced by `std::string`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that the first compiler error?

```
   table_info* table_info;
   table_info = get_table_info(tablename);
   table_info new_table;
```

In the first line you are creating a local variable `table_info` that hides the type `table_info` in the outer context. The third line should be a compiler error telling you that the syntax is wrong. From there on, whatever the compiler had tried to interpret does not yield it to believe that `new_table` is an object of type `table_info`.

Answer (score 2):

You declared a variable named `table_info`, and there's a type named `table_info`, and that's confusing the compiler. When I ran  this through g++, it started complaining at the line

```
table_info new_table;
```

because at that point `table_info` is a variable name, not a type name any longer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was the similar 'table_info' that confused the compiler. The error went away when I changed the local variable name to table_infos.